# Swift: Determine the type of this constant

Tags: swift, types, type-deduction

What is exactly the type of this const (val)?

```
let val = { (a: Int, b:Int)->Int in a + b }(1 , 2)
```

Isn't it `(Int,Int) -> Int` ?

Comment: Did you notice the `(1 , 2)` at the end?

Comment: This is exactly the same as `let val = (+)(1,2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just `Int`, because it takes only the final result, you call a function there that takes 2 Ints and return their adding result, which is going to be 3

In order to determine the type of a variable in the future you could just hold `option` key on the keyboard and hover over the variable name

Answer (score 1):

There's already a good answer here, but I'd like to provide some more details for the records.

The following is a [closure expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95) of type `(Int, Int)->Int`:

```
{ (a: Int, b:Int)->Int in a + b }
```

You could as well have defined an equivalent named function:

```
func f (_ a: Int, _ b:Int)->Int { a+b }
```

You could then have called the function with two parameters to get an `Int` value:

```
let val = f(1,2)
```

And you can do the same thing by replacing the function name with a closure expression:

```
let val = { (a: Int, b:Int)->Int in a + b }(1 , 2)
```

You could even combine the two practice and display step by step the type:

```
let l = { (a: Int, b:Int)->Int in a + b }    // name the closure using a variable
print (type(of: l))                          // (Int, Int)->Int
let val = l(1 , 2)                           // use the closure 
print (type(of: val))                        // Int
print (val)
```